# Where to find english labels for tensorflow hub classify modules

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to use the `https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/classification/1` module as is without modification to make inferences using the original set of labels (if for no other reason than to verify that I have it working correctly before modifying it).

I need a way to map the output logits back to English. This example https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py shows the english mappings packaged with the checkpoint files. The checkpoint files for the versions on docker hub do not have similar mappings (that I can find) http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28.tar.gz.

How can I map the output logits of a tensorflow hub model back to english?

Answer (score 1):

After digging in to the tfslim model source I found some utilities for this.

Summarized here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/461fc09474d8f532b9c0250dd54b885c537df99f/research/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb

But, essentially:

```
from datasets import imagenet
# ^ this module does not exist in a package repo as far as I can tell.
# I just manually downloaded it and its dependencies from the above repo.

...
names = imagenet.create_readable_names_for_imagenet_labels()
print('Probability %0.2f%% => [%s]' % (probabilities[index] * 100, names[index]))
```